# Texmaker pdflatex compile error with libertine font after updating Texlive 2012

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, libertine

After updating the texlive 2012 in Ubuntu 12.04 by

```
# tlmgr update --all
```

I found `pdflatex` (within Texmaker) cannot compile a TeX file with the Libertine font

```
\usepackage{libertine}                        % libertine
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
```

However, in Terminal the tex file can be compiled by the command

```
$ pdflatex  thesis.tex
```

I even uninstalled and reinstalled Texmaker, the problem still persists.

Comment: In what sense "Texmaker" cannot compile? What's the error?

Comment: This is the error info:   pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file fxlb-xl-8x): Font fxlb-xl-8x at 720 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: I suspect that Texmaker is using the TeX Live/Debian distribution, rather than the "vanilla" that's used when you compile from the shell. Can you add the first lines of the log file obtained when you compile from Texmaker?

Comment: You are right.  LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2012.11.19) 27 DEC 2012 15:30
entering extended mode

Comment: Since you appear to be using `tlmgr`, you have installed also the "vanilla" TeX Live; so this seems a path problem; check in Texmaker's preferences for how the `pdflatex` command is called.

Comment: I found Texmaker pdflatex can not compile new added/revised Latex fonts: like New TX, Libertine, etc. But it is okay with old fonts.

Comment: The problem is that Texmaker seems to use the Debian TeX Live.

Comment: Could you please explain more about how you solved your problem? It seems as if I have exactly the same problem but I don't understand how you solved it in the end. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a path problem.

If you have installed the "vanilla" TeXLive, it is not enough to add the new PATH in your`.profile` file (or any configuration fill used by your shell like `cshrc` or `.zshrc`...) because this configuration file is not used by your graphic environment (gnome, kde, xfce...).

For graphic environment, there is no such file for each user (omission in freedesktop?)!

In Debian/Ubuntu distribution, you can add the new PATH in the `/etc/environment` file (via `sudo`). Replace:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

by:

```
PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

(where `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux` is the TeXLive path on x86_64 architecture. On i386 architecture, choose `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux`.)

Comment: Bashrc setting: `export TEXMFDIST=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist     
export`,      `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux:$PATH`,    The path was set since Texlive 2012 being installed. Weird thing is that it works in my Laptop but not in my office PC. (Both computers have same OS - Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: @KOF Your bashrc settings is *not* used by Texmaker! TexMaker uses it if it is launched from a terminal...

Comment: @KOF Launch `texmaker` from a terminal with the correct PATH and try again (`xelatex` calls implicitly `dvipdfmx` and uses PATH to found it. So, your PATH **must** be correct.)

Answer (score 4):

the names of the files for Libertine changed with the latest update. But your installed TeX-distribution always searches in the Ubuntu configuration and not in the TUG-TeXLive one. You should delete the Ubuntu TeXLive and then install the dummy package

http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/Ubuntu/texlive-dummy_1.0_all.deb

and then setting the pathes as shown in http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/Ubuntu/zzz-texlive.sh

Comment: Well, it's old version of texlive 2011~

Comment: do you mean the deb file?

Comment: Is there such Ubuntu version of texlive 2012?

Comment: I think so, but it has no TeXLive manager for daily updates! This is only possible with the TUG TeXLive

Comment: That's what i have installed from TUG

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems when using xelatex from TexLive 2012 in TexMaker.  I believe it's a $PATH issue in that TexMaker doesn't know where to find the correct commands, even when using the explicit path.  I never solved the problem but I completely removed TexLive 2012 and installed the Ubuntu version via apt.  After that xelatex docs compile normally.

Addendum:  Just looked through my email and TexMaker support confirmed it's a path problem.  He didn't say how to fix it, just that it's a path problem.

Kent

Comment: The path of pdflatex shown in Terminal is: $ which pdflatex: /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex. While in Texmaker it's like: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex. Can I set this corresponding to the system path?

Comment: Problem solved by $ updmap as user (not as root)!

Answer (score 0):

I found a universal solution for this issue:

Just `delete all of the texlive 2012 related files/folders in your Home folder`, and completely remove `Texmaker`.

Then reinstall texmaker and the installation will automatically search for the right path for fonts and execute files.

Comment: and TeXmaker depends to Ubuntus TeXLive and will install it again except when you install TeXmaker from the sources.